# Save entity using javascript and symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, doctrine

I want to save an entity using javascript and symfony,

```
this is an example
<form method="post" action="" id="form-step2" class="form-vertical">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Inputs</legend>
      <div id="extender"></div>
      <p><a id="add_btn" href="#">Add</a></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/vWPJf/57/)

when clicking on the add button, a function in the controller should be called and the entity should be saved or updated to the database, same thing when clicking remove button, the entity should be updated.

Comment: You can associate a route to a controller action and call it in an ajax routine and voila.

Comment: my problems really i  how using ajax with symfony ( I mean using submit form with ajax),